# V-Lookup across multiple arrays

Tags: excel, nested, vlookup, lookup, sumproduct

I am having trouble using lookup functions to achieve the following.

From Table-1, I need to look-up the Items list, and depending on what type of item it is (Fruit/Veg/Seed), pull in the corresponding percentage to Table-2.  I have tried to so this using Vlookup and nested IFs but its not working.

[image]

```
=IF((VLOOKUP($A$10:$A$16,$A$1:$E$8,2,FALSE)=$B$9),$C$1:$C$8,IF((VLOOKUP($A$10:$A$16,$A$1:$E$8,4,FALSE)= $E$1:$E$8,""))
```

Comment: Do you only ever have 2 categories (CAT1/2) or can it be more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two `VLOOKUP`'s.  The first for Cat-1, and the second for Cat-2:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($B13,$B$4:$F$10,2,FALSE)=C$12,VLOOKUP($B13,$B$4:$F$10,3,FALSE),
IF(VLOOKUP($B13,$B$4:$F$10,4,FALSE)=C$12,VLOOKUP($B13,$B$4:$F$10,5,FALSE),""))
```

Enter in `C13` and fill across and down.

The second `VLOOKUP` is entered into the `value_if_false` portion of the first `IF`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your help. This worked well.